# learning random function in Python

Tags: python, random

I have got the following error message for the script below. Can someone tell me what is the mistake I have made?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "random.py", line 1, in <module>
    import random
  File "C:\Users\premj\Desktop\py4e\random.py", line 4, in <module>
    x = random.random()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

```
import random

for i in range(10):
    x = random.random()
    print (x)
```

Comment: You named the file containing your code `random.py`, so it will try to import itself instead of the `random` module of the standard library. Just change the name of your file.

Comment: Don't name your file `random.py` it name clashes with the `random` library.

Comment: I have changed the file name to prem.py. Still coming out with error as follows:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prem.py", line 1, in <module>
    import random
  File "C:\Users\premj\Desktop\py4e\random.py", line 4, in <module>
    x = random.random()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't a `random.py` still laying around?`

Comment: Thanks Thierry Lathuille. Now I have deleted the random.py file and it is working.

Comment: Try running print(dir(random)) after you import random

Comment: Thanks Rohit Sthapit

Answer (score 0):

When the interpreter executes the "import random" statement, it searches for random.py in a list of directories:

1. The directory from which your script was run
2. The list of directories contained in the PYTHONPATH environment variable, if it is set.
3. An installation list of directories configured when Python was installed

So, in your case, you are trying to import your own script, because it's named "random.py". Just change your script name like "test.py".

Comment: Note that usage of name test.py can sometimes lead to unexpected side effects since `test` is part of standard library. See, for example https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/1339